# Edit fields of a jsonb array in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.5

I have the following jsonb in db:

```
[
    {
        "state": 2,
        "activity": "EJECUCIÓN",
        "final_date": "2020-02-24",
        "activity_id": 1,
        "current_days": -7,
        "initial_date": "2020-02-24",

    },
    {
        "state": 2,
        "activity": "REVISIÓN",
        "final_date": "2020-02-25",
        "activity_id": 2,
        "current_days": 0,
        "initial_date": "2020-02-25",

    },
    {
        "state": 2,    
        "activity": "RECEPCIÓN",
        "final_date": "2020-02-27",
        "activity_id": 4,
        "current_days": 0,
        "initial_date": "2020-02-27"


    } ]
```

I run the following query to update the current_days field:

```
WITH activity_state     as  ( SELECT taex_id,('{'||index-1||',current_days}')::text[] as pathe ,
        ((task_activity->>'final_date')::date - current_date) as current_days,
        task_activity->'state' as state,
        task_activity->>'final_date' as final_date,
        task_activity->>'current_days' as curren   FROM task_executions,jsonb_array_elements(taex_activitygraph) with ordinality arr(task_activity,index)   WHERE task_activity->>'state' = '2'  )  

update task_executions SET  taex_activitygraph = jsonb_set(taex_activitygraph,activity_state.pathe,to_jsonb(current_days),true) FROM activity_state  WHERE task_executions.taex_id = activity_state.taex_id  AND activity_state.state = '2'
```

But that query only updates me the first element of the JSON array that exists the others do not undergo changes although in the first part of the query.

```
( SELECT taex_id,('{'||index-1||',current_days}')::text[] as pathe ,
        ((task_activity->>'final_date')::date - current_date) as current_days,
        task_activity->'state' as state,
        task_activity->>'final_date' as final_date,
        task_activity->>'current_days' as curren   FROM task_executions,jsonb_array_elements(taex_activitygraph) with ordinality arr(task_activity,index)   WHERE task_activity->>'state' = '2'  )
```

It brings me all the elements of the array that should be updated but the second part that is where it is supposed to update them:

```
update task_executions SET  taex_activitygraph = jsonb_set(taex_activitygraph,activity_state.pathe,to_jsonb(current_days),true) FROM activity_state  WHERE task_executions.taex_id = activity_state.taex_id  AND activity_state.state = '2'
```

Just update me the first item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this structure and data:

```
postgres=# \d task_executions 
               Table "public.task_executions"
       Column       | Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------------------+-------+-----------+----------+---------
 task_activitygraph | jsonb |           |          | 

postgres=# SELECT jsonb_pretty(task_activitygraph) FROM task_executions ;
             jsonb_pretty             
--------------------------------------
 [                                   +
     {                               +
         "state": 2,                 +
         "activity": "EJECUCIÓN",    +
         "final_date": "2020-02-24", +
         "activity_id": 1,           +
         "current_days": -7,         +
         "initial_date": "2020-02-24"+
     },                              +
     {                               +
         "state": 2,                 +
         "activity": "REVISIÓN",     +
         "final_date": "2020-02-25", +
         "activity_id": 2,           +
         "current_days": 0,          +
         "initial_date": "2020-02-25"+
     }                               +
 ]
(1 row)
```

... this UPDATE should work:

```
postgres=# UPDATE task_executions
SET task_activitygraph = (
  SELECT jsonb_agg(
    CASE WHEN elem->>'state' = '2'
    THEN 
      jsonb_set(
        elem,
        '{current_days}',
        to_jsonb((elem->>'final_date')::date - current_date)
      )
    ELSE
      elem
    END
  )
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(task_activitygraph) AS a(elem)
);
UPDATE 1
```

Documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

Side note: In transactional databases (where you have many concurrent clients, and processing speed and storage efficiency matters), and if your objects have fixed structure, **DO NOT STORE your data as JSON**. Use relational data model instead.

Comment: Thank you
what you answered works but ....

WHERE
 final_date < current_date

to_jsonb((elem->>'final_date')::date - current_date)

WHERE
 (elem->>'initial_date') <= current_date 
 AND (elem->>'final_date' )>= current_date

to_jsonb((elem->>'initial_date')::date - current_date)


in theory that towards the condition in my query

Comment: @DarioPaez excuse me, not clear what you mean, could you update your original question with specific what you want to achieve? (also table structure would be helpful)

Comment: in the update you send you don't consider the activity_state condition.

Comment: @DarioPaez got it, updated. (with `CASE` statement inside `jsonb_agg`)